# Binding not working + everything is same as in the example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, telerik

Here is the example: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/ajaxbinding

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<AXBCore.AccountTemplate>()
    .Name("Grid1")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(110);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Amount).Width(110);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Timestamp).Width(110);
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_AjaxBinding", "Settings"))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable()
)
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. I had two grids with the same name. So, the second one didn't work.